# Ember.js computed property not firing

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a computed property thats not firing when a checkbox is checked. I just need to switch a property's value from 1 to 0 if its checked.

```
App.Address = Ember.Object.extend({
  shipType: 1,

  shipType: function() {
    var type = this.get('shipType');
    if (type === 1) {
      type = 0;
      return type;
    } else {
      type = 1;
      return type;
    };
  }.property('shipCommerical')
})
```

And in my template:

```
<label>{{view Ember.Checkbox checkedBinding='shipCommerical'}} Check Me </label>
```

I have other computed properties located in the same place and in the same way. The only difference is they are text fields and not checkboxes. Does that make a difference?

Comment: can you create a fiddle or jsbin please.

Comment: You have a couple weird things going on here. First you have 2 shipTypes in your object (the keys should be unique). Also you need to depend on the `shipType` property for the computed property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you've got ship commercial spelled incorrectly, but it appears you have it spelled incorrectly in both places.  Additionally you have a recursive loop where your computed property needs itself, I'm going to assume you meant to use `shipCommercial` instead of `shipType` inside the computed property.

#### Template

```
<label>{{input type='checkbox' checked=shipCommercial}} Check Me </label>
```

#### Properties

```
shipCommercial:true,
shipType: function() {
  var shipCommercial = this.get('shipCommercial');
  return shipCommercial ? 0 : 1;
}.property('shipCommercial')
```

#### Example

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zimopise/1/edit